# Getting model data associated with a username and displaying it in HTML in Django

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model that associates points and donations with a user. In my view, I want to get the data for the user who is currently logged in and display his donations and points in HTML. How would I go about doing this? The model, view, and HTML are down below.

View (I want to get the points and donations assosicated with the user currently logged in).:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request,'dashboard.html', )
```

Model:

```
  class userdetails(models.Model):
      donations = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True,)
      points = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True,)
      user = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            blank=True,
            null=True,
        )
```

Comment: The *same* user can have *zero*, *one* or *multiple* related `userdetails`, hence there is not a *single* `points` or `donations`, but a *collection*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs on render][1] you can pass in `context`, a dictionary of values to add to the template context. So in your view you will need to something along the lines of:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    # assuming there is exactly one
    # this will break if there are multiple or if there are zero
    # You can (And should) add your own checks on how many userdetails objects you have for the user
    # consider using a OneToOneField instead of a ForeignKey
    user_details = user.userdetails_set.get()  # or userdetails.objects.get(user=user)
    context = {
        "donations": user_details.donations,
        "points": user_details.points,
    }
    return render(request,'dashboard.html', context=context)
```

Then in your HTML you can use [Django's template language][2]:

```
<div class="box">
                   <span class="value">{{ points }}</span>  
                   <span class="parameter">Points</span>
                </div>


<div class="box">
                   <span class="value">{{ donations }}</span>  
                   <span class="parameter">Donations</span>
                </div>


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render
  [2]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#variables
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! It really helped me. Just wondering, would this work if I have different users? For example, if I have 1 donation and 2 points on one account, and I switch to another account with 15 donations and 11 points, would it display their points? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The same user can have zero, one or multiple related userdetails, hence there is not a single points or donations, but a collection.

Two scenario's are likely to handle the data: 1. we enumerate over the different `userdetails` and render these items; or 2. we sum up the `points` and the `donations` and display the sum of these fields.

## Option 1: enumerating over the collection

Here we thus pass our collection of related `userdetails`:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    details = userdetails.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'dashboard.html', {'details': details})
```

and in the template we render these with:

```
{% for detail in details %}
  <div class="box">
    <span class="value">{{ detail.points }}</span>
    <span class="parameter">Points</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="value">{{ detail.donations }}</span>
    <span class="parameter">Donations</span>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

## Option 2: aggregate the objects together

We can calculate the sum of the points and donations with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    data = request.user.userdetails.aggregate(
        total_points=Sum('points'),
        total_donations=Sum('donations')
    )
    return render(request,'dashboard.html', data)
```

then we can render this with:

```
<div class="box">
  <span class="value">{{ total_points }}</span>
  <span class="parameter">Points</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span class="value">{{ total_donations }}</span>
  <span class="parameter">Donations</span>
</div>
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`userdetails`</s> to `UserDetail`.